# Goto specific frame depending on a randomly generated number in Actionscript 2

Tags: if-statement, random, actionscript, actionscript-2, goto

I've been trying to get a piece of code working for a while, but I can't seem to find what's wrong with it.

My goal is this:
press a button, the button will generate a random number between 1 and 100 (to simulate percentage) then, depending on what number is drawn, it will gotoAndStop on a specific frame.

I tested the code, and the random number generation works fine; but it won't continue to the frame it's supposed to go to. Instead, it goes to the last frame in the sequence
(example: here, the frame it will move to are 151, 152, 153, ..., 160, 161.
So the faulty code will generate a random number just fine, but will always goto frame 161, regardless of the number generated)

Here is the code I was using:

```
on (release) {
TIME = random (100);
if(0 < TIME < 6) {
    gotoAndStop(151);
}
if(5 < TIME < 13) {
    gotoAndStop(152);
}
if(12 < TIME < 33) {
    gotoAndStop(153);
}
if(32 < TIME < 48) {
    gotoAndStop(154);
}
if(47 < TIME < 61) {
    gotoAndStop(155);
}
if(60 < TIME < 72) {
    gotoAndStop(156);
}
if(71 < TIME < 81) {
    gotoAndStop(157);
}
if(80 < TIME < 89) {
    gotoAndStop(158);
}
if(88 < TIME < 95) {
    gotoAndStop(159);
}
if(94 < TIME < 99) {
    gotoAndStop(160);
}
if(98 < TIME < 101) {
    gotoAndStop(161);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check explicitly the different conditions:

```
if(0 < TIME && TIME < 6) { /* ... */}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare a variable against 2 other values at once like this `0 < TIME < 6`, as it will compare `0 < TIME` which returns boolean `true` most of the time in this example, then cast it to `1` for comparison against `6`, which is always `true`. Sames goes for `101`, which is why it always goes to the last frame. You need to use `0 < TIME && TIME < 6` or this more efficient alternative.

```
on (release) {
    TIME = random (100);
    if(TIME < 6) {
        gotoAndStop(151);
    }
    else if(TIME < 13) {
        gotoAndStop(152);
    }
    else if(TIME < 33) {
        gotoAndStop(153);
    }
    else if(TIME < 48) {
        gotoAndStop(154);
    }
    else if(TIME < 61) {
        gotoAndStop(155);
    }
    else if(TIME < 72) {
        gotoAndStop(156);
    }
    else if(TIME < 81) {
        gotoAndStop(157);
    }
    else if(TIME < 89) {
        gotoAndStop(158);
    }
    else if(TIME < 95) {
        gotoAndStop(159);
    }
    else if(TIME < 99) {
        gotoAndStop(160);
    }
    else if(TIME < 101) {
        gotoAndStop(161);
    }
}
```